# Tablet not recognized as removable storage

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode

I have an Android A-13 Android tablet version 4.0.4 Baseband version 4.0.14  I have been trying to get my PC to recognize it so that I can download my music to it.

But I do not know if the PC does recognize it or not as the tablet does not show up on the removable storage. I have tried several different things to get it to do so but none of them work.

One of the attempted things is to enable USB mass storage on the tablet. But when I try to do that it does not have a place for it in the Settings. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: When you plug it into the computer, does a notification show up in the status bar asking if you want to mount it, or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

On Android 4.0+ devices, certain devices without a separate memory partition (i.e. separate sd card) don't have the **USB Mass Storage** option, rather Android now uses [**MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) or [**PTP (Picture Transfer Protocol)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Transfer_Protocol) to transfer files.

NOTE: If your device supports SD Cards, please make sure that an SD card is available in the device before connecting it to the PC.

To configure between MTP and PTP (and USB Mass Storage if an SD card is available): go to **Settings > Device > Storage > Menu > USB computer connection.**

To **transfer files to your device via MTP**, make sure it is in the MTP mode, then connect it to your computer via a USB cable.

On Windows: wait for Windows to install the necessary drivers, then your device will be available in My Computer. ([more info](https://support.google.com/android/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1650161&topic=1650156&ctx=topic))

On Mac: You have to install the Android File Transfer software. Follow the steps on this [support page](https://support.google.com/android/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1649773).

On Ubuntu: follow the steps in [this article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-connect-your-android-ice-cream-sandwich-phone-to-ubuntu-for-file-access).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the SD card from phone/tablet.
Put it in a card reader or laptop card reader.
Can you open it?
You may need to try a couple of times,
When you do get it to open, run scandisk (right-click the drive, select properties, open Tools tab, select scandisk).

After scan and repair, defrag the SD Card.
This should fix any file errors, you should be good to go.

If the SD card wont open, maybe you need to try downloading the free Minitool Partition Wizard software. This should access the card and allow you to rescue data. (The Rescue My Files program is also good)

*Sigh* If all this fails, format the card and get a new life but this time subscribe to a free cloud backup system.

Answer (score 0):

I Factory Reset my tablet (On the Lenovo TAB 2, select Settings, Backup and reset, Factory data reset). All my data and apps were erased, but it was worth it since all but one of the apps were free anyway and the lost photos were easily replaced from my laptop. This solved the problem.